# Azure Data Lake Analytics Vs Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

I am using ADF to connect to sources and get data into Azure Data Lake store. After getting data into Data Lake Store, I want to do some transformation, aggregation  and use that data in SSRS reports and also for creating Cubes.

Can anyone suggest me which will be the best option (Azure Data Lake Analytics or Azure SQL DW)  ?

I am looking here to make a decision on to take which one after Data lake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons to use Azure Data Lake Analytics vs Traditional ETL approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852489/reasons-to-use-azure-data-lake-analytics-vs-traditional-etl-approach)

Answer (score 4):

There are no more Azure SQL DW. What we have now are Azure Synapse (same as Azure DW) and Azure Synapse Analytics (instead of Azure Datalake analytics). Microsoft is stopping support (develop) USQL and Azure Datalake analytic. If volume of your data is huge and you want use Polybase technology the best choice is Azure Synapse and Azure Synapse Analytics. You can rich your ADF by using Databricks to do analytics stuff. By using Polybase you can do ELT instead of ETL.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Azure is not anymore investing on Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) , you can evidently see that number of enhancements /updates in last couple of years are almost none in ADLA. While on the other side Azure SQL Data Warehouse is their flagship service ( recently names as azure synapse analytics) and hence getting enhanced and updated very fast. Synapse is based on MPP architecture and provides all required capabilities of big data computing.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your data? Azure Data Lake is more meant for petabyte size big data processing and Azure SQL Data Warehouse for large relational DWH solutions (starting from 250/500 GB and up).

With Azure Data Lake you can even have the data from a data lake feed a NoSQL database, a SSAS cube, a data mart, or go right into Power BI. With Azure SQL Datawarehouse you can have cubes, Power BI reports and SSRS

If you need SQL Server Reporting Services, Integration Services (and you have complex SSIS logic), and Analysis Services (SSAS), you may better consider an Azure SQL VM.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. Data size is huge and the plan is to have data lake store as staging layer and use that for Analytics using ADLA in future and for visualization planning to create  Azure DW with ADL as source.

Comment: As per my Understanding we cant use ADLA instead of Azure SQL DW rite? for Visualization purpose.